# VBA moving specific worksheet before/ after selected worksheet takes too long - why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple code which is moving worksheet "Data" to after activated worksheet.

```
Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Worksheets("Data").Move After:=Worksheets(Sh.Name)
  Worksheets(Sh.Name).Activate
End Sub
```

I am using

```
Worksheets(Sh.Name).Activate
```

because without this line worksheet "Data" remains selected after the move which is not the intention.

The problem I have is when this code is run it takes about 2-3 seconds for excel to think about it before seeing result.

I don't understand why. Without chaining these 2 operations together it takes milliseconds. Could someone please explain how to improve this and why is this happening?

Comment: There might be several reason of such behaviour, for example: another macro which is used to calculate some values. I'd check if `Data` sheet is active then change the order of sheets. BTW: can you elaborate why `Data` sheet should be inactive?

Comment: Or why you need Sh to be Active? If you have other code using `ActiveSheet`, you can replace that in a variety of ways...

Comment: Your code will enter an endless loop - more than 2-3 seconds I'd have thought. You need to disable events before running it.

Comment: Btw `Worksheets(Sh.Name)` is equivalent to `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be quicker:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim nam As String

    nam = Sh.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Worksheets("Data").Move After:=Worksheets(nam)
        Worksheets(nam).Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of recursive calling: when you use `.Activate`, then your `Sub` `Workbook_SheetActivate` is called again and you're stuck in an endless loop.

If you simply want to **deselect** the data range, you can use `Cells(1,1).Select` and you can directly use `Sh` instead of using `Worksheets(Sh.Name)`, since they're equivalent.

So your final code would be:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   Worksheets("Data").Move After:=Sh
   Cells(1,1).Select
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys. Turning off/on events helped to get out of the loop.

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Worksheets("Data").Move After:=Sh
    sh.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I should have probably explained what the code was being used for in my question.

The user had 50+ Worksheets in the Workbook (please don't ask me why :)). They had one in particular ("Data") they wanted to be able to click in and out whilst working with other worksheets. So this code was simply causing the Worksheet "Data" to "follow them"

The line:

```
sh.Activate
```

Was used to get back to the Worksheet they have just clicked on as otherwise they were getting stuck on "Data" Worksheet.